# Why does Adafruit but not fastLED work with WS2812 LED strips and Arduino Nano?

Tags: arduino, led, adafruit, fastled

I am using the Adafruit_NeoPixel library and Arduino Nano to light up my WS2812 RGB LED strips.

Now I had to switch to the fastLED library because I fond an awesome program, but strangely, using any of the demos my LEDs remain black. With Adafruit_NeoPixel they work perfectly.

Anyone know this problem? Is it a hardware problem? Usually I just have to enter PIN and NUMPIXELS and the demos do the rest.

Answer (score 2):

I have finally the answer.
The answer is that I was using an old fastLED library. One from 2014: FastLED 3.0.
My Library Manager was presenting only version 3.1.6, but this was not used until I manually deleted the whole folder with the 3.0 version.
Now fastLED demos run with my Arduino Nano with the WS2812 LED strips.